# Getting Text from Edittext Another Layout

Tags: android, string, layout, android-edittext

I have many layouts, but i just want to take the strings from several different layouts.
My problem is what i got is just null....

Here is my code :

```
    LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
    View input = factory.inflate(R.layout.activity_inputan, null);
    View coordinate = factory.inflate(R.layout.activity_location, null);
    View scan = factory.inflate(R.layout.activity_scan, null);

    EditText prod = (EditText) input.findViewById(R.id.product);
    EditText bran = (EditText) input.findViewById(R.id.brand);
    EditText plac = (EditText) input.findViewById(R.id.place);
    EditText date = (EditText) input.findViewById(R.id.date);
    EditText pric = (EditText) input.findViewById(R.id.price);
    EditText lat = (EditText) coordinate.findViewById(R.id.latitude);
    EditText longi = (EditText) coordinate.findViewById(R.id.longitude);
    EditText format = (EditText) scan.findViewById(R.id.format);
    EditText content = (EditText) scan.findViewById(R.id.content);

    String a = prod.getText().toString(); 
    String b = bran.getText().toString(); 
    String c = plac.getText().toString();
    String d = date.getText().toString(); 
    String e = pric.getText().toString();
    String f = lat.getText().toString();
    String g = longi.getText().toString();
    String h = format.getText().toString();
    String i = content.getText().toString();
```

I tried to show it in another layout through a toast, but it's null.
Any help or advices appreciated.

Comment: What do you means by another layout? are those in a same `Activity`? if those are NOT in the same `Activity`. you can NOT do so. when the `Activity` gone, all its children views gone too.

Comment: No... it's totally a different activity.... so, i can't do that? i think there must be some way... I just dont know yet.. But thx for the reply..

Comment: Try to put your strings in an `Activity` to another `Activity` through the method `Intent#putExtra(id,value)`, and retrieve by `Intent#getExtraString(id)` in that `Activity`. Hope this helps.

Comment: wow..... i remind me of that. Thank you very much. I'll try that now.... Thank you very much once again

Comment: Depending on your demands and the structure of the app, there are multiple ways to realize that. You could also look into handlers and receivers, as well as background services. Then, you could also try to think of a singleton main application activity or data sharing via SharedPreferences or a database... can't judge that because I do not know the size of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Create a LayoutInflater.

```
LayoutInflater inf = getLayoutInflater();
View v1 = inf.inflate(R.layout.regis, null);
EditText user = (EditText) v1.findViewById(R.id.edt1); 
String usr = user.getText().toString();
```